# Why can't common type in binary operator be inferred?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings

I'm getting the compiler warning "Cannot infer a common type; 'Object' assumed." from the following code:

```
Dim occurrence As CacheableDocumentOccurrence = _
    If(DirectCast(IdentityMap.GetItem(id), CacheableDocumentOccurrence),
        Function() As CacheableDocumentOccurrence
            Dim x = New CacheableDocumentOccurrence()
            IdentityMap.Add(x)
            Return x
        End Function)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `If` statement returns a `CacheableDocumentOccurrence` if `GetItem(id)` returns not `Nothing`, but returns a `Function` (lambda expression) otherwise!
You must return a `CacheableDocumentOccurrence` in both cases.

```
Dim occurrence As CacheableDocumentOccurrence = DirectCast(IdentityMap.GetItem(id)
If occurrence  Is Nothing Then
    occurrence = New CacheableDocumentOccurrence()
    IdentityMap.Add(x)
End If
```

Note that your function is not just a parenthesis around some code. It would not be executed anyway; instead, the result would be an AddressOf Function.

Comment: Ahhh...right, of course.  I was trying to be clever doing everything in one statement.  Your example is the way I would have usually done it.

Comment: and is two lines shorter! Well, one if you put the `If` line behind the `=`.